# PHP fails to download Excel file that is generated by PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to download excel file (instead of saving it). Since I want to export HTML table I am using PHPExcel_reader_HTML to read contents of HTML table. Excel file is created perfectly when I want to save it but when I want to download it, nothing happens. Does someone knows where's the problem?

Code:

```
<?php
// Load the table view into a variable
$html = $_POST["table"];
require_once('php/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
// Put the html into a temporary file
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$tmpfile = time().'.html';
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $html);

// Read the contents of the file into PHPExcel Reader class
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML; 
$content = $reader->load($tmpfile); 

// Pass to writer and output as needed
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"results.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$objWriter->save("php://output");
ob_clean();
// Delete temporary file
unlink($tmpfile);
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @web-nomad No. It just stays there forever...

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php

Comment: @VicAbreu Thanks for replay. This code is for creating new excel file. Is there way to pass data to it from HTML table?

Comment: @jureispro, check these two links: 
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/42richText.php
http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/class-PHPExcel_Writer_HTML.html

A couple a months ago i wrote a script to generate xlsx based on HTML, using PHPExcel, but i have no longer access to it. :( 

By the way (just for reference), you can save an HTML FILE as a xlsx and Excel is going to understand it without no problem.